# Anyone could help me with this trig question

Tags: trigonometry

It  says Prove that $\cos^2(A) = 1-2 \sin(2A)$

by $\cos(A+B)=\cos(A) \cos(B) - \sin(A) \sin(B)$?

Was thinking of using this formula to get started 
$\cos(A) + \cos(B)$ ? is it possible to use the product formula?

Comment: It can't be proved, which you want because the above one is not valid for any value of angle A.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $$\cos(2A)=\cos(A+A)=\cos(A)\times\cos(A)-\sin(A)\times\sin(A)=\cos^2(A)-\sin^2(A)=(1-\sin^2(A))-\sin^2(A)=1-2\sin^2(A)$$

Comment: How you use Cos(2A)?

Comment: I have to use the Cos(a+b) formula to prove the top one

Comment: @user66288: I wrote $\cos(2A)=\cos(A+A)$.

Comment: It's not correct answer ... You have to prove something else (Ist line that OP wanted) but you proved different one

Comment: It's the correct answer, but it's not the correct question :-)